# How to target a single element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to set up an unordered list of ingredients. On click, an ingredient (`<li>`) should have its `background-color` made yellow.

With the below code, I am able to click on ingredients and change the background color. However, I am unable to target a single element. How can I make it so that, on click, only that `<li>` has its background color changed?

```js
$('#lili>li').click(function () {
  $('li').css('background-color', 'yellow');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ingred">
  <h3>INGREDIENTS</h3>
  <ul id="lili">
    <li>3 Tbsp soy sauce</li>
    <li>1 teaspoon brown sugar</li>
    <li>1 Tbsp olive oil</li>
    <li>2/3 cup diced red onion</li>
    <li>2/3 cup diced red bell pepper</li>
    <li>2 cloves garlic, minced</li>
    <li>1-inch piece of ginger, grated</li>
    <li>3 eggs, well beaten</li>
    <li>4 cups day old cooked white rice (from about 2 cups of raw rice)</li>
    <li>1 cup frozen peas, thawed</li>
    <li>2 cups cooked salmon in large chunks</li>
    <li>2 green onions, thinly sliced, including the greens</li>
    <li>Cilantro (or parsley) for garnish</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: use   $(this).css('background-color','yellow');

Comment: write   $(this).css('background-color','yellow');. "This" refers to the current clicked object, otherwise your code will change all the "li"

Comment: Take a moment to look over your question's [revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30723928/revisions) and note how your question has changed from its initial posting. In the future, try to make your questions as clear and concise as possible. Formatting is extremely important (I cannot stress this enough). Salutations and other trivialities are just that: unnecessary. By exposing the problem to the best of your ability and by trimming away the fluff, you increase the chance that you'll find help. (This is your first question on SO, so I figured I'd give some pointers.)

Comment: Thanks... I had tried $('this') and not $(this).  Syntax matters!

Answer (score 4):

Use `this` to target clicked li , `li` will target all the `li`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#lili>li').click(function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'yellow');
    //-^-----
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>INGREDIENTS</h3>
<ul id="lili">
  <li>3 Tbsp soy sauce</li>
  <li>1 teaspoon brown sugar</li>
  <li>1 Tbsp olive oil</li>
  <li>2/3 cup diced red onion</li>
  <li>2/3 cup diced red bell pepper</li>
  <li>2 cloves garlic, minced</li>
  <li>1-inch piece of ginger, grated</li>
  <li>3 eggs, well beaten</li>
  <li>4 cups day old cooked white rice (from about 2 cups of raw rice)</li>
  <li>1 cup frozen peas, thawed</li>
  <li>2 cups cooked salmon in large chunks</li>
  <li>2 green onions, thinly sliced, including the greens</li>
  <li>Cilantro (or parsley) for garnish</li>

</ul>
```

If you want to toggle the effect then use the following,

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#lili>li').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('toggle');
  });
});
```

```css
.toggle {
  background-color: yellow
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>INGREDIENTS</h3>
<ul id="lili">
  <li>3 Tbsp soy sauce</li>
  <li>1 teaspoon brown sugar</li>
  <li>1 Tbsp olive oil</li>
  <li>2/3 cup diced red onion</li>
  <li>2/3 cup diced red bell pepper</li>
  <li>2 cloves garlic, minced</li>
  <li>1-inch piece of ginger, grated</li>
  <li>3 eggs, well beaten</li>
  <li>4 cups day old cooked white rice (from about 2 cups of raw rice)</li>
  <li>1 cup frozen peas, thawed</li>
  <li>2 cups cooked salmon in large chunks</li>
  <li>2 green onions, thinly sliced, including the greens</li>
  <li>Cilantro (or parsley) for garnish</li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the css of even source not all the li elements

```
$(this).css('background-color','yellow');
```

You can also use the native method for setting background-color like, which will be faster then the previous one

```
this.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `this`, as this refer to current clicked element.

```
  $(this).css('background-color','yellow');
```